# Flexbox parent container not growing along with its children? Content inside is overflowing out of the parent div

Tags: html, css

**[JsFiddle demonstrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/rroqeygu/3/)**

I have two divs, A and B, inside of a container. As B's content grows, I would expect the container and A to grow along with it. However, rather than doing that, the content in B overflows, which causes the page layout to break.

All of the heights are set to 100%. Why is content overflowing?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.side {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.mycontainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycontainer">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <div>
      <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
      <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
      <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
      <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just remove `height` from container and side, or set it `auto`:

the overflow happens because 100% is initial size of html.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.side {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: auto;
}

.mycontainer {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
}

.main {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.expand {
  height: 400px;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

.expand:hover {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycontainer">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <div>
      <div class="expand"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

ps: for demonstrate block resizes, just use expanders, to make less noise code.

Comment: Setting height: auto worked for me, but I also had to remove min-height.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set a `min-height` on the parent (e.g. `body {min-height: 100vh;}` as an example). This way it will allow the parent container to continue to grow as necessary.